# NUnit 3.8 - does params in NUnit command line console have cache?

Tags: caching, parameters, console, nunit

I'm using Nunit console 3.8 in my automation tests.
When I run the same command with different param value in the same machine few times, I see that the first value in all cases.

Does Nunit consoles' params have a cache on the disk? Can we clear it?

```
"c:\...\nunit3-console.exe" <DLL List> --params=testLevel=Sanity /where:"cat == <some_category>" 

"c:\...\nunit3-console.exe" <DLL List> --params=testLevel=Regression /where:"cat == <some_category>"
```

Comment: The params definitely don't have a cache, so I expect it is a mistake in your test code or a misunderstanding of how Params work. Can you share some test code?

Comment: You are right :) Thank you!